# How do I define a Python property *outside* of a class definition?

Tags: python, properties

I would like to define a Python property *outside* of a class definition:

```
c = C()
c.user = property(lambda self: User.objects.get(self.user_id))
print c.user.email
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'email'
```

What is the correct syntax for defining a property outside of a class definition?

Btw: I'm using [lettuce](http://lettuce.it/)

```
from lettuce import *
from django.test.client import Client
Client.user_id = property(lambda self: self.browser.session.get('_auth_user_id'))
Client.user = property(lambda self: User.objects.get(self.user_id))

@before.each_scenario 
def set_browser(scenario):
    world.browser = Client()
```

Answer (score 19):

Object instances like `c` cannot have properties; only classes like `C` can have properties. So you need to set the property on the class, not the instance, because Python only looks for it on the class:

```
C.user = property(lambda self: User.objects.get(self.user_id))
```

Comment: Hm, I tried that but I get this error: AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: If you get *that* error, then it means that this problem has more moving parts than you have been willing to admit in your question. :) Please show us you actual code and what `import` statements and libraries you are using. In return, we will show you why you are getting a thread-local error!

Comment: Are you getting that error on the line that starts with `Client.user =`? I cannot even see in their source code where Django *or* Celery uses thread locals at all, and I cannot reproduce your problem (the script you offer does not run stand-alone if I put it in a `.py` file).