# Make Method Act Like Property Outside a Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties

On classes you can create properties:

```
class foo():
    _bar = None
    @property
    def bar(self):
       return self._bar
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @bar.setter
    def (self, value):
        """"""
        self._bar = value
```

Which is awesome, but I was wondering if it was possible to extend `@property` and `setter` outside the class setting.

So in a module I could have:

```
_bar = None
@property
def bar():
   return _bar
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
@bar.setter
def (self, value):
  _bar = value
```

That way I can have this operation bar on the module level:

```
>>> print(mymodule.bar)
None
>>> mymodule.bar = "Fish"
>>> print(mymodule.bar)
Fish
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define a Python property \*outside\* of a class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948691/how-do-i-define-a-python-property-outside-of-a-class-definition)

Comment: You can't. Properties only work in combination with a class.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can) is also relevant.

Comment: This is the best question today, _bar = None. ;-)