# Python dynamic alias for an object attribute rather than get just a value of attribute (get actual dict key value)

Tags: python

I have the next code:

```
current_money = my_dict[long_key_1][long_key_2]...[users][user][one_more_long_key][current_money]
```

I want to access `current_money` without typing this long line every time,
but `current_money` is immutable `int`, saving it to variable will not hold an actual value.

How I can easy create alias to access an `current_money` actual value?

Sure I can create function, but `assert get_current_money() == 10` not looks so clean,
moreover, in my case `current_money` isn't `int`, it's becomes:
`get_current_money().attribute.method().attribute == 10`.

One of solutions that I know it's `property`.
`@property` decorator will force me to add > 20 lines of code just for an aliasing.
`property` function may better fit to this case, but it's pretty obscure:

```
current_money = type('current_money_alias',
                     (),
                     {
                         'my_dict': {'long_key_name': 1},
                         'p': property(lambda self: self.d['a'])
                     })()  # Call just in place
```

or

```
# This is not working, property not bind
current_money_alias = SimpleNamespace(my_dict={'long_key_name': 1},
                                      current_money=property(lambda self: (self.my_dict['long_key_name'])),
                                      )
```

Most short way to assign property it's:

```
C.user = property(lambda self: User.objects.get(self.user_id))
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948728/11277611
```

But assigning custom attributes not allowed to dict.

Well, there should be definitely a better solution, it's not required to be exactly with `property` .

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the full expression you gave will not allow you to update the value.  But you could stop one level short:

```
user_alias = my_dict[long_key_1][long_key_2]...[users][user]
user_alias[current_money] = new_value
```

Comment: Actually, the last key (`user`) is tuple and also very long

Comment: @salius the length of that last key doesn't matter, Python is very efficient in creating and using aliases (references).

Comment: So, it will be already 2 aliases eventually, the path to dict/object and the key itself. Looks not so efficient :)

Comment: @salius try it before you jump to any conclusions.  I think you'll be surprised.